# pytest programmatically change pytest.ini default

Tags: pytest

We are using pytest for test automation and have a pytest plugin.  The question i have is, i would like to modify the test collection default for anyone using the plugin.  By default pytest only collects methods with class name beginning with Test, this can be modified by adding pytest.ini file in the rootdir, where the tests are.  However, i would like to change this default for anyone using my plugin so they dont have to add the pytest.ini file.  Looking for a hook to modify this default, or read it in from somewhere else within the plugin.

Answer (score 2):

found the answer

```html
session.config.inicfg["python_files"] = "*.py"
session.config.inicfg["python_classes"] = "*"
```

the first line makes all python files eligible while the second line makes all classes eligible for collection.